# NSURLConnection/Session. GET request. sending parameters as data, and not part of the URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm only familiar with making GET request from manually constructing a string of parameters with the url. I was told by the admin of the API that they are not set up to parse my parameters and that I have to send a JSON array of parameters. In this case, it is a parameter of phone numbers.

I'm familiar with sending data an an POST request via:

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error
```

But that doesn't seem like an option to me for GET methods.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? If you need to send data you use POST,you can not send data with GET. Note: While it is possible to send data in a GET command with curl that is not allowed by the GET specifications and is an artifact of curl allowing things it should not.

Comment: @Zaph According the relevant [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) it is not explicitly forbidden to send a body with a GET request. It's semantic is just not defined and a server may reject the request. So, this is actually an "implementation defined behavior" - defined by the server.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper `NSURLConnection` does not support sending data in a `GET` request. Data can be added it but it will not be sent.

Comment: @Zaph I would say this is a bug.

Comment: From RFC 7231: "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;"

Answer (score 0):

For an URI, the *query component* (see section 3.4 [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) is additional "non-hierarchical" data that specifies the resource referenced in the hierarchical path component.

Frequently, the query component is a comma separated list of key/value pairs. But it doesn't need to. The semantics of this "string" can be defined by the server. This could be a certain JSON as well.

Perhaps, this is what the admin of the API actually is talking about.

If this is true, you can send a JSON as the query component. Ensure, the JSON string is properly encoded and then appended to the URI after appending the `?` separator.

You can also use `NSURLComponents` to compose this URI:

Suppose, your "query" is some custom JSON which should contain an SQL where-clause:

```
NSURLComponents* components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSString* query = @"{\"where\":\"name='value1' OR name='value2'\"}";        
components.query = query;
```

This example will construct a URI whose encoded query component will look as below:

**%7B%22where%22:%22name='value1'%20OR%20name='value2'%22%7D**